A short sci-fi/horror story about an ink blot type alien creature 70’s or 80’s
The story begins with the creature in the forest relating the story from its perspective. It has sustained itself on small animals but appears to need more intelligent life forms to absorb.
The creature comes upon a hunter and chases him down and engulfs and absorbs him.  A sheriff deputy is next after the hunter is reported missing and he goes to search for him.
I was very young and I can’t remember much more other than this story was in a collection of short sci fi stories.

Reminds me of "*" by Gahan Wilson. It appeared in the 1972 anthology Again, Dangerous Visions, edited by Harlan Ellison. The story is not told from the perspective of the blob, however. Also identified on SFF:SE here.

Perhaps this is "Slime", by Joseph Payne Brennan? The blob monster comes from the ocean rather than space. It washes up in a swamp and evolves to survive ashore, hunting first animals, then humans. The early part of the story follows the monster, with no human characters until later.

I second @StanleyWebb's suggestion for it being "Slime".

Very like Someone You Can Build a Nest In by John Wiswell (2024) - Shesheshen is a shapeshifter, who happily resides as an amorphous lump at the bottom of a ruined manor. When her rest is interrupted by hunters intent on murdering her, she constructs a body from the remains of past meals: a metal chain for a backbone, borrowed bones for limbs, and a bear trap as an extra mouth.

Your description has many similarities to the short story "Slime", by Joseph Payne Brennan. "Slime" first appeared in the March 1953 issue of "Weird Tales Magazine", but has been anthologized many times since. (I've read the story in "Alfred Hitchcock's Monster Museum", and "Monsters, Monsters, Monsters") The story begins in the deep ocean, describing the monster's habit of feeding on the fiercest of the sea's predators, which are helpless against it. A geological upheaval casts the monster ashore, in Wharton's Swamp, near the town of Clinton Center. The monster quickly adapts itself to land life, and feeds on myriads of small animals before taking an eccentric farmer's cow. The farmer is the first human character to appear in the story. After that, the monster takes a hobo and a hunter. The hunter's dog escapes. Next the monster takes a young man. The man's girlfriend escapes, and tells her story to the skeptical sheriff. The sheriff sends out search parties, then switches to two-man night patrols. One patrol is attacked, and one man dies. The other man, who carries a powerful flashlight, escapes due to the monster's hatred of light. (The monster's slithering sound as it travels is described several times, as is its horrible smell) The sheriff calls in the army, and the monster is stalked in its lair. The tale's conclusion switches between monster and human viewpoint. There is no particular human hero in the story, the monster is the main character.


Could this be Theodore Sturgeon's It?
An large amorphous monstrous shape forms about an old skeleton in the forest and comes to life. The beginning of the story is in third person, but recounts the inner feelings of the creature.
It kills various things including a "field creature", a beloved dog and its owner (who is a hunter); nearly kills a man searching the woods, and menaces the child of the dog owner's brother.
Disconnects with points mentioned in the question: No law enforcement folks; doesn't really absorb its victims, just rips them apart.
One of Sturgeon's great early stories.
The Luminist Archive has a pdf of its original appearance in the August 1940 Unknown here. It's been frequently anthologized, often in horror collections.
